# Sort array in JavaScript based on name and order parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

In my current project I have to sort an array of objects based on specific sort parameters:

the order (up / down),

and the sort type(name, description, category).

Therefore I created a sort array with syntax `sort = [type, order]`.

Now I want to sort my array of objects based on the sort type and order.
My current implementation is:

```
  computed: {
accountsList() {
  var list = this.$store.getters["accounts/accountsList"];
  if (this.$route.query.fave) {
    list = list.filter((x) => x.fave == true);
  } else if (this.$route.query.my) {
    //my
  }
  if (this.sort.length != 0) {
    list = list.sort((a, b) => {
      if (this.sort[1] == "up") {
        if (a[this.sort[0]] < b[this.sort[0]]) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a[this.sort[0]] > b[this.sort[0]]) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      } else {
        if (a[this.sort[0]] < b[this.sort[0]]) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a[this.sort[0]] > b[this.sort[0]]) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
  return list;
},
```

My sort array is changed like this:

```
  changeSort(sort, order) {
      if (this.sort[0] == sort && this.sort[1] == order) {
        this.sort = [];
      } else {
        this.sort = [sort, order];
      }
```

My array of objects consists of:

```
[{ category: "test2",
description: "adadad",
name: "adadadadad"
},
{
category: "test",
description: "my description",
name: "NewAccount"
​​​},
{
category: "test",
description: "My other description",
​​​name: "another new account"
}]
```

At the moment it's not working properly, it's just sorting two elements and leaves the other ones untouched.

Comment: can you show sample of that of this.sort array. ?

Comment: I just added my changeSort-method to the post

Comment: Please don't use Stack Snippets for non-runnable examples, just use code blocks. Stack Snippets are for **runnable** examples. (A runnable example would be good, though. :-) )

Comment: Please show the contents of the array you're trying to sort. (I think that's what @robert meant to ask for above, but they said `this.sort` and I think they meant `list`.)

Comment: The parameters sort and order are given by the <span>-tag the user clicks on. As stated above the sort-type is a parameter type the object has and the order type is either up or down.

Comment: just show us your data, and tell how to you want to sort it, by which parameters. in my opinion your code samples are so twisted that i have really problem to figure out what you try to doing.

Comment: just added the list content

Comment: Why not UPDATE the snippets you had with a [mcve]

Comment: What im trying to do: The data is rendered in a table, the user has the possibility to sort name, category or description either ascending or descending. Therefore the array with the object type and the sort type

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lodash's orderBy function as the example below:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];
 
_.orderBy(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

For further reference: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify Your code and ask a question - do You return `list`? Maybe You could supply a whole method, or even fully working example.

```js
export {
  data() {
    list: []
  },
  methods: {
    sortList() {
      if (this.sort.length != 0) {
        let col = this.sort[0] || 'id', // default col
            dir = this.sort[1];

        this.list = this.list.sort((a, b) => {
           let colA = a[col], 
               colB = b[col];
     
           if (dir == "up") {
             return (colA  < colB ? 1 : (colA  > colB ? -1 : 0))
           } else {
             return (colA  < colB ? -1 : (colA  > colB ? 1 : 0))
           }
        });
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: yup, the sort method is in the `computed`-property of my vue object.